# Motion: Unable to open device

Tags: webcam, motion

I can access the web interface but get a grey screen then saying "Unable to open device".

I tried:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ ls /dev/video*
pi@octopi:~ $ /dev/video0
```

I can also take pictures with fswebcam so the hardware is working.

There seems to be a problem with /var/run/motion/motion.pid
I tried give all permissions but the error is still there.

Here is the output from the command motion:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ motion
[0] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "sdl_threadnr"
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 3.2.12+git20140228 Started
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to syslog
[0] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[0] [NTC] [ALL] become_daemon: Motion going to daemon mode
[0] [ERR] [ALL] myfopen: Error opening file /var/run/motion/motion.pid with mode w+:

Broadcast message from systemd-journald@octopi (Sat 2017-07-08 21:41:39 UTC):

motion[718]: [0] [EMG] [ALL] become_daemon: Exit motion, cannot create process id file (pid file) /var/run/motion/motion.pid:


Message from syslogd@octopi at Jul  8 21:41:39 ...
motion: [0] [EMG] [ALL] become_daemon: Exit motion, cannot create process id file (pid file) /var/run/motion/motion.pid:
[0] [EMG] [ALL] become_daemon: Exit motion, cannot create process id file (pid file) /var/run/motion/motion.pid:
```

Comment: you might need to create /var/run/motion - 'mkdir /var/run/motion'

Answer (score 1):

A crash or unclean shutdown can leave the **motion.pid** file behind. If this file exists the new process can't create the file.

You can solve this by removing the **motion.pid** file. To remove the file use the following command:

```
rm /var/run/motion/motion.pid
```

You may need to prepend the above command with **sudo**

Answer (score 0):

For me it were some permission settings that had to be changed. Running these as root fixed the error:

```
touch /var/run/motion/motion.pid
chown root:motion /var/run/motion/motion.pid
chmod o+w /var/run/motion/motion.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked many places to find a solution. I also add a grey screen. Then I decided to uninstall Infrared module and it worked. Then I reinstalled infrared module onto the camera module, but I installed infrared modules over camera module or not under as it was. Now it works perfectly. I think that putting infrared modules under decrease the voltage and this is the reason why it didn't work. I hope that this could help some of you

Thanks for all your support

Comment: I don't see how an infrared module is relevant to the question.